# Need help at PHP regex want to parse content

Tags: php, html, regex, web-crawler

I am having problem with this code as I am not getting the required output.

I need to collect content include between two tags.

I used:

```
$p_d=preg_match("/<a class=\"production-details-works\">(.*?)<div class=\"production-details-synopsis\".+>/s",$f);
```

Where `$f` is HTML content I already parse. `$p_d` is variable where I have to store my new content.

Tags I have used in `preg_match` already content more tags like `<strong>` and `<br>` and `<p>`. I need content with including these tags as I have to replace `<br>` tag with some other text.

Please help.

Comment: $p_d=preg_match("/<p class=\"production-details-works\">(.*?)<div class=\"production-details-synopsis\".+>/s",$f);

Comment: "Please help", "need help" and "want to" aren't used for questions, but support requests; which are off-topic. Your 'question' lacks proper input examples and reasoning on why you're not using a HTML traversal library alternatively to a regex.

Comment: I am using simple_html_dom.php

Comment: simple_html_dom.php is used in code..........I got $f from it now I wont particular content from $f through preg_match. I cant use 'find' again as html code is complex and different. Content is  between two tags as I mentioned.so want to use preg_match if you have any other way you are welcome to solve it.